# Android: Login on specific aspx website and retrieve data from it

Tags: android, web, post, authentication, jsoup

I'm developing an Android application that should login on this website http://siga.cps.sp.gov.br/aluno/login.aspx with username/password provided by the user from the EditTexts, when the user press proceed button the application should login on the website and then retrieve data from the html code from the next page which is this one: http://siga.cps.sp.gov.br/aluno/home.aspx and show information on TextViews

For retrieving data from HTML I can retrieve all that I need using Jsoup, but the thing is, I have no idea how to programmatically access the page that requires login before access to start data retrieving

If anybody can lend me a hand over here, it would much appreciated

Comment: post the values of all the form's inputs to the target of the form's action, the response should be the next page

Comment: OK, I think I understood what you mean, but I don't know how to do it

I do not have much experience dealing with web programming so far

Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: try OkHttp3, this link might help you https://www.dev2qa.com/android-okhttp3-http-get-post-request-example/